# jQuery get JSON response is empty

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I'm trying to get a simple jQuery get JSON call to work.  Neither my success handler non error handler seems to be getting called.  Firebug also shows the data body as empty.

The server is a very basic bit of code running under web.py.  I've tested the server by connecting to it with lynx and it downloads the json data OK.

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/settings.json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(json){
            alert('json success ' + json);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
});

JSON data is:
{"netmask": "255.255.0.0", "ipaddress": "192.168.1.153"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't make a request to another domain (that rule includes a different port) with an XmlHttpRequest, this is blocked by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

The result of *trying* to do this is an empty response, so you can't see the content.  This is just a rule in place for security purposes...if you're connecting to the same host and port, it's a non-issue.

Comment: you can't be sure that the OP is making a cross-domain call. and also, a cross-domain call usually throws up an exception.

Comment: @fred: So for instance, if you're testing this by opening the HTML file directly from a file browser (so you end up with a URL in your address bar starting with `file://`), that's a different *origin* than your `http://localhost:8080` path. If you are loading the HTML file via a URL starting with `http://localhost:8080` then this isn't an origin problem, it's something else.

Comment: @anirvan - it doesn't throw an exception, it depends on the browser as to *what* it does...what I can see is a port in the URL and this tale-tale symptom: "Firebug also shows the data body as empty"...that's *exactly* what happens when you make the request this way (cross-domain), and it works fine otherwise... *exactly* like the OP is experiencing :)

Comment: Thanks guys, actually I am connecting to the same server but a different port.  I'm serving the file with the javascript with apache on port 80 and my REST server is running on 8080.  Is there any simple way to get the request to the different port to work?

Comment: @anirvan: For instance, with Chrome, the request fails if the SOP kills it when the document is `http://`, but not when the document is `file://` (you get the blank data). Example: http://jsbin.com/imuda5/2 Run that from JSBin on Chrome and it'll fail. Copy it to a local file and run it, and the Ajax call will "succeed" but `data` will be blank. YMMV across browsers (or even browser versions).

Comment: @fred: If you're in control of both ends (and it sounds like you are), you can use [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) on a browser that supports it. Otherwise, you're looking at [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) or (for public-facing stuff) a [YQL proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax).

Comment: @fred - nope, it's just not allowed...you can disable it from the command line for some browsers, but this won't help other users...no chance of serving things from the same server (using apache for both?)

Comment: @Nick: Recommend "The result of *trying* to do this is either an error or an empty response." as current versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Opera all trigger an error on `http` to `http` with different origins. (Opera also does on `file` => `http`; Chrome and Firefox do the empty response thing.)

Comment: @T.J. - You *may* see an error in the console, but the JavaScript callback will *still* execute, and get an empty response :)

Comment: @Nick: Not in my tests. See the example I did for anirvan (http://jsbin.com/imuda5/2). Chrome, Opera, and Firefox all trigger the `error` function, not `success` with an empty body (but they do the empty body thing if you grab that locally and run it as a `file://` document).

Comment: @T.J. - That's **jQuery** failing, it is still getting a response though, use an XMLHttpRequest directly to see it happening: http://jsbin.com/imuda5/3

Comment: @Nick: Well, the OP is using jQuery, so at the level of abstraction they're using, it's an error. But it is anyway, look at the status code: http://jsbin.com/imuda5/4 It's `0` rather than `2xx`. (I also fixed the typo, the /3 version is trying to go to google.comt [with the t].) Obviously it **should** be something more useful than `0`, but still... :-) And this explains jQuery being inconsistent, it's apparently concluding that a status of `0` with a blank response is an error (reasonable conclusion).

Comment: @T.J. - The reason I'm answering in JavaScript and not specific to his abstraction is because it *is* inconsistent, and that `0` check was changed to not be a success (because of Opera showing a 304 as a 0) back in 1.4.3 IIRC...anyway my response was to @anirvan's original comment about requests in general.  jQuery may change how it handles this later, but the basic behavior of the underlying request is the same here.  *If* I was answering the OP then I would phrase it differently, but none of this was for the OP  :)

Comment: @Nick: Actually, it's not even looking at the blank response. If it sees status == 0 and the URL wasn't a `file` URL, it says it's an error: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#LC636

Comment: @T.J. - Right, it didn't do this with `0` previously (because of Opera), look at 1.4.2: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/ajax.js#L550-553

Comment: @Nick: That was just overlapping comments, not a response to your last comment. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a reverse proxy in Apache that will make a remote data source look like it's coming from a local domain. I've written a blog post about how to do this:

http://senchabits.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/problem-accessing-json-data-from-a-local-data-source-is-not-permitted/

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround to get an error callback with an empty response in cross domain requests.

In this example I'm using Zepto, a light-weight version of jQuery, but I assume that this works fine in jQuery too.

First of all, you must use these parameters to do a cross domain request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: 'application/x-javascript',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data, status) { /* ... */ }
    error: function () { /* ... */ }
    // ...
```

Now, the **$.ajax** function internally use the **$.ajaxJSONP** for crossdomain requests. This is the original Zepto **$.ajaxJSONP** function:

```
  $.ajaxJSONP = function(options){
    var callbackName = 'jsonp' + (++jsonpID),
      script = document.createElement('script'),
      abort = function(){
        $(script).remove()
        if (callbackName in window) window[callbackName] = empty
        ajaxComplete('abort', xhr, options)
      },
      xhr = { abort: abort }, abortTimeout

    if (options.error) script.onerror = function() {
      xhr.abort()
      options.error()
    }

    window[callbackName] = function(data){
      clearTimeout(abortTimeout)
      $(script).remove()
      delete window[callbackName]
      ajaxSuccess(data, xhr, options)
    }

    serializeData(options)
    script.src = options.url.replace(/=\?/, '=' + callbackName)
    $('head').append(script)

    if (options.timeout > 0) abortTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        xhr.abort()
        ajaxComplete('timeout', xhr, options)
      }, options.timeout)

    return xhr
  }
```

My workaround is very simple and consists on an interval called few times on the script.onload event handler, in order to verify that the callback function was called.

This is my version of the **$.ajaxJSONP** function:

```
$.ajaxJSONP = function(options){
    var called = false, // Flag to check that callback was called
        callbackName = 'jsonp' + (++jsonpID),
        script = document.createElement('script'),
        abort = function(){
            $(script).remove()
            if (callbackName in window) window[callbackName] = empty
            ajaxComplete('abort', xhr, options)
        },
        xhr = { abort: abort }, abortTimeout

    if (options.error) {
        script.onerror = function() {
            xhr.abort()
            options.error()
        };

        // IMPORTANT!!!
        script.onload = function () {
            var times = 0;

            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                // After 5 intervals, if the callback wasn't called, returns an error
                if (times++ == 5) {
                    clearInterval(interval);

                    if (!called) {
                        options.error();
                    }
                } else if (called) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 100);
        };
    }

    window[callbackName] = function(data){
        // Setting the "called" flag to true
        called = true;
        clearTimeout(abortTimeout)
        $(script).remove()
        delete window[callbackName]
        ajaxSuccess(data, xhr, options)
    }

    serializeData(options)
    script.src = options.url.replace(/=\?/, '=' + callbackName)
    $('head').append(script)

    if (options.timeout > 0) abortTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        xhr.abort()
        ajaxComplete('timeout', xhr, options)
    }, options.timeout)

    return xhr
}
```

Note: If you are interested in the server side behavior, please see the beginning of this tutorial: http://phonegap.com/2011/07/20/making-jsonp-calls-with-zepto-on-android-device/